# SingleInstance Form pass new arguments to open form

Tags: c#

I have a C# windows form that is set to SingleInstance using the tutorial provided by Microsoft found here: [Windows Forms single instance application (CSWinFormSingleInstanceApp)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormSingleInstanceApp-d1791628). What I am having issues with is getting any of the additional arguments that are added after the first one.

**Program.cs:**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    SingleInstanceAppStarter.Start((args.Length == 0
        ? new frm_remPhotoViewer(string.Empty)
        : new frm_remPhotoViewer(args[0])),
        StartNewInstance);
}

static void StartNewInstance(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
{
    FormCollection forms = Application.OpenForms;
    //MessageBox.Show(e.CommandLine[1]);
    if (forms["frm_remPhotoViewer"] != null
        && forms["frm_remPhotoViewer"].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        forms["frm_remPhotoViewer"].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        forms["frm_remPhotoViewer"].Activate();
    }
    else if (forms["frm_remPhotoViewer"] == null)
    {
        frm_remPhotoViewer f = new frm_remPhotoViewer("HELP ME!!!");
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**SingleInstanceAppStarter.cs:**

```
static SingleInstanceApp app = null;

// Construct SingleInstanceApp object, and invoke its run method.
public static void Start(Form f, StartupNextInstanceEventHandler handler)
{
    if (app == null && f != null)
        app = new SingleInstanceApp(f);

    // Wire up StartupNextInstance event handler.
    app.StartupNextInstance += handler;
    app.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
}
```

**SingleInstanceAppHelper.cs:**

```
public SingleInstanceApp()
{
}

public SingleInstanceApp(Form f)
{
    // Set IsSingleInstance property to true to make the application 
    base.IsSingleInstance = true;
    // Set MainForm of the application.
    this.MainForm = f;
}
```

The line that is commented out is the text I am looking to add to the active form.

Answer (score 1):

I may not exactly understand what you mean by getting additional arguments after the first one... but think you are referring to the command-line arguments via

```
void Main(string[] args)
```

You are creating your form with.

```
new frm_remPhotoViewer(string.Empty) 
or
new frm_remPhotoViewer(args[0])
```

but appear to want the possibility of args[0], args[1], etc...

Why not just set the constructor parameter of your form from excepting a single string to accepting an ARRAY of strings

```
public YourFormConstructor( string someParm )
to
public YourFormConstructor( string[] someParmArray )
```

Then, in your form's constructor you can do your test on the length of the array and do whatever you need to there..  ex:

```
public YourFormConstructor( string[] someParmArray )
{
   if( someParmArray.Length == 0 )
      form.SomeProperty = string.Empty;
   else
   {
      foreach( string s in someParmArray )
      {
         // do something based on each string "s" provided..
         if( s.StartsWith( "-aCommandLineArgumentFlag1" ))
           blah...

         if( s.StartsWith( "-aDiffCommandLineArgumentFlag" ))
           blah...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what  was doing before I made it a single instance program, but since I made it a single instance program I was unable to pass new arguments to the form once it is open. So for example: If I open an image and it opens my program and then in 5 minutes I open the image again it doesn't open a new instance but where the messagebox is where the new location appears, but I can't figure out how to get it to send it to the already open form.

Answer (score -1):

```
 static class Program
    {

        static MainForm mainForm;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(params string[] Arguments)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            mainForm = new MainForm(Arguments);
            SingleInstanceApplication.Run(mainForm, NewInstanceHandler);

        }

        public static void NewInstanceHandler(object sender, StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
        {
            mainForm.FileName(e.CommandLine[1]);

            e.BringToForeground = false;
        }

        public class SingleInstanceApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
        {
            private SingleInstanceApplication()
            {
                base.IsSingleInstance = true;

            }

            public static void Run(RibbonForm f, StartupNextInstanceEventHandler startupHandler)
            {
                SingleInstanceApplication app = new SingleInstanceApplication();
                app.MainForm= f;
                if (f.DialogResult != DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    app.StartupNextInstance += startupHandler;
                    app.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
                }
            }



        }
//add this to MainForm
public void FileName(string args)
 {  }
```